# Polymorphic Relations in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

There isn't much documentation on polymorphic relationships in Ember.js. So far, the only thing I could find was in the [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/750) itself. Unfortunately, following that example hasn't led to a working app. Here's what my models looks like:

```
Whistlr.Event = DS.Model.extend
  eventable: DS.belongsTo 'eventable',
    polymorphic: true

Whistlr.Eventable = DS.Model.extend
  events: DS.hasMany 'event'

Whistlr.Organization = Whistlr.Eventable.extend
  name: DS.attr()
```

The payload looks like this:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "eventable_id": 1,
            "eventable_type": "organization"
        }
    ]
}
```

And then I try rendering this in my layout:

```
ul
  each event in controller
    li = event.eventable.name
```

Unfortunately, this results in a list with many empty `li`s. Each li is rendered, but the `event.eventable.name` is coming back blank. Is there something wrong with my approach? How can I render the name for each eventable?

UPDATE:

When I examine the Data with Chrome's Ember Extension, I see that the each entry for eventable is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use 'eventable' key instead of 'eventable_id' and 'eventableType' instead of 'eventable_type' in payload:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "eventable": 1,
            "eventableType": "organization"
        }
    ]
}
```

example - http://jsbin.com/EGiZuL/1

Comment: It throws this error: `Error: assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: factory is undefined`

Comment: That could very well be. I'm actually using the canary build right now and I'm still get this error, but I suspect it's because I'm not handling aliasing properly. I opened a [second question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371465/setting-an-polymorphic-alias-with-ember-data-1-0beta) about how to alias with Ember-Data 1.0Beta.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I missed your edit. Once `eventable_type` becomes `eventableType`, everything works as expected. Thanks, Anton!